# Python data type not recognized

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

I have the below code. This piece of code creates and display a covid data on a dash dashboard.I need to add a datepicker to this and display the data that applies to that range.

I get the error "ValueError: format number 1 of "2020-01-01" is not recognized" when doing so.The values input by the datepicker cannot be converted to the datetime format in order for me to filter out records that belongs to that date range from the initial dataframe.any help with this is highly appreciated.

Due to this mismatch I run in to errors whenever I try to print the data type of the received data or during the line where I compare the dates.

```
import pandas as pd
from dash import html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash import dcc
import dash
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

import datetime

df = pd.read_excel("https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.xlsx")
#
from numpy import dtype

app = dash.Dash()

# df = pd.read_csv('new2.csv', index_col=0)
print(df)
print(df.columns.tolist())
df.drop(
    df.columns.difference(['continent', 'location', 'date', 'total_cases', 'new_cases', 'total_deaths', 'new_deaths']),
    1, inplace=True)
print(df)
df.to_csv('new3.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

app.layout = html.Div(id='parent', children=[

    html.H1(id='H1', children='Covid Dashboard', style={'textAlign': 'center', \
                                                        'marginTop': 40, 'marginBottom': 40}),

    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='my-date-picker-range',
        min_date_allowed=date(2020, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=date.today(),
        initial_visible_month=date(2020, 1, 1),
        # end_date=date.today()
        display_format='YYYY-MM-DD',
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-range'),

    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown',
                 options=[
                     {'label': 'Total cases', 'value': 'total_cases'},
                     {'label': 'New cases', 'value': 'new_cases'},
                     {'label': 'Total_deaths', 'value': 'total_deaths'},
                     {'label': 'New deaths', 'value': 'new_deaths'},
                 ],
                 value='total_cases'),
    dcc.Graph(id='bar_plot')
])


@app.callback(Output(component_id='bar_plot', component_property='figure'),
              [Input(component_id='dropdown', component_property='value'),
               Input('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
               Input('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date')
               ])
def graph_update(dropdown_value, start_date, end_date):
    print(dropdown_value)
    print(start_date)
    print(end_date)
    start_date1 = '{}'.format(start_date)
    end_date1 = '{}'.format(end_date)


    # to get the world subset since the dataset contains multiple locations
    worldwide_subset = df.loc[df['location'] == 'World']

    if start_date is not None and end_date is not None:
        # date_object = date.fromisoformat(start_date)
        # print(date_object)
        start_date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date1, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        end_date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date1, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        print('...............')

        
        mask = (df['date'] > start_date_object) & (df['date'] <= end_date_object)
        print(df.loc[mask])
        used_df = df.loc[mask]
        print(used_df)
    else:
        used_df = worldwide_subset

    fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=used_df['date'], y=df['{}'.format(dropdown_value)], \
                                line=dict(color='firebrick', width=4))
                     ])

    fig.update_layout(title=dropdown_value + ' over time',
                      xaxis_title='date',
                      yaxis_title=dropdown_value
                      )
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

error trace

```
[2021-12-01 21:12:24,710] ERROR in app: Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sithijathewahettige/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/dash/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/sithijathewahettige/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/dash/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/sithijathewahettige/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/dash/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/sithijathewahettige/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/dash/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/sithijathewahettige/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/dash/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1336, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "/home/sithijathewahettige/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/dash/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash/_callback.py", line 151, in add_context
    output_value = func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "dimi2.py", line 86, in graph_update
    mask = (df['date'] > start_date_object) & (df['date'] <= end_date_object)
  File "/home/sithijathewahettige/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/dash/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 69, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "/home/sithijathewahettige/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/dash/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py", line 48, in __gt__
    return self._cmp_method(other, operator.gt)
  File "/home/sithijathewahettige/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/dash/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 5502, in _cmp_method
    res_values = ops.comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  File "/home/sithijathewahettige/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/dash/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 284, in comparison_op
    res_values = comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, lvalues, rvalues)
  File "/home/sithijathewahettige/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/dash/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 73, in comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY
    result = libops.scalar_compare(x.ravel(), y, op)
  File "pandas/_libs/ops.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_compare
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'
```

Comment: can you give the whole trace - most importantly which line raises the error?

Comment: mask = (df['date'] > start_date_object) & (df['date'] <= end_date_object)

Comment: `df["date"]` is presumably a string. Try doing `df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])` after `pd.read_excel`

Answer (score 0):

The error you got `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'` means you should convert the string (`str`) to `date` before you can filter them. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':['2020-01-01','2020-02-02','2020-03-03','2021-12-01']})
print(df)
```

Dataframe:

```
      date
0  2020-01-01
1  2020-02-02
2  2020-03-03
3  2021-12-01
```

If you `type(df['date'][0])` then you see it is a `str` but if you `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])[0]` then the type is `Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')`

Doing `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` will output:

```
0   2020-01-01
1   2020-02-02
2   2020-03-03
3   2021-12-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can filter dates doing:

```
df[(df['date'] > '2020-01-20') & (df['date'] < '2021-03-20')]
```

output:

```
         date
1  2020-02-02
2  2020-03-03
```